# Display multiplayed numbers in Prime Factor (Python)

Tags: python, primes

I am doing Project Euler and I just finished problem #3.

This is the code I made:

```
num = 600851475143

values = []

i = 1

for n in range(1, num):

    if num % (i+0) == 0:
        values.append(n)

    if len(values) == 10:
        break

    i += 1

prod = 1

for v in values:

    prod *= v

    if prod == num:
        print('Largest prime factor of 600851475143 is', v)
        break
```

How can I print the numbers which have been multiplied until the prime factor number appers (included this last one) ?

So, just the first 5 numbers of `print(values)` ?

Comment: How about `values[:5]` ?

Comment: I could do, yes, but what if the number `num` change ? I would like to automatize it..

Comment: Automatize it to what?  I did not gather that from your question. Do you mean the values used until the break?

Comment: If I put `values[:5]` will work with the given number. But if I change `num` variable to 305, `[:5]` will break because there arent 5 prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To print all of the `values` used before the break, you can do something like:

```
for i, v in enumerate(values):
    prod *= v
    if prod == num:
        print('Largest prime factor of {} is {}'.format(num, v))
        print('Numbers used:', values[:i])
        break
```

Comment: That's it. I would add `+1` to `i` in `print('Numbers used:', values[:i])` to include also the prime factor.
Thanks